# when I put my PS3 on the fan make a loud noise and with in a seconds it will go off

Tags: ps3

After cleaning my PS3 super slim when I switch it on the fan will just make a loud noise and go off with in a seconds.

Before I cleaned it, it was working perfectly but after cleaning it begin to cause this problem. What can I do?

Comment: When you say you "cleaned it", do you mean you cleaned the outside of the PS3 to remove the dust and dirt, or did you also take it apart and clean the inside?

Comment: I opened it and clean out all the dust.

Comment: @Konaldo2 Sounds like you made a mistake when opening or closing it. The only possible solution (aside from sending it in for repairs or buying a new one), is to open it up again and see if you accidentally unplugged some cable or forgot to plug it back again.